# SSIS - This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

I am writing a package to upload result of query to FTP as CSV file.

Package is working fine on local machine, but after transferring .dtsConfig and .dtsx on another environment it throws following error message after executing all tasks in package.

> Description: The connection "{008A2775-60D6-44B1-8790-69958EB74371}"
>   is not found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the
>   specific connection element is not found.  End Error  Error:
>   2014-11-24 07:32:05.79     Code: 0xC001000E     Source: PackageName
>   Description: The connection "{008A2775-60D6-44B1-8790-69958EB74371}"
>   is not found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the
>   specific connection element is not found.  End Error  DTExec: The
>   package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  7:32:05 AM 
>   Finished: 7:32:07 AM  Elapsed:  1.81 seconds.  The package execution
>   failed.  The step failed.

any idea what will be the reason?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem lies in the referencing. You might have copied the package from an older one and are making the changes or you might have edited the connection managers. The connection managers are internally used using the GUID that you have mentioned. You might have changed most of the references from the UI, but still there are some objects and tasks, that are referencing the deleted or older connection managers. The probable one would be the **SQL Server Logging** in the package.

Solution is: Open the code of the package, by **right clicking** the **package** in the **solution explorer** and clicking on **View Code** which shows the package code in XML format. Now you are able to see, which tasks are referencing the old connection manager. Do the needful changes and this should do it!

Let me know if the problem persists after this!!

Comment: Thanks. This is great. I was struggling to find that missing connection and later found it in xml and then delete from package explorer. issue was solved.